# Apache Felix File Install jar from deploy folder

Tags: java, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-felix

I am trying to use `Apache Felix File Install` with an embedded version of Felix. The basic idea is simple, I have a jar application file that can be launched using standard `java -jar app.jar` and the application will startup Apache Felix framework and then look in a `hot deploy` folder installing, updating and removing the OSGi bundles that are in/placed/updated/removed from that folder at runtime.

I currently have managed to create the ability to startup the embedded Felix and I can deploy bundles if I specify them via `BundleContext.installBundle()` but I cant get the `jar` bundles to be dynamically harvested  from the hot folder.

This is what I currently have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("felix.fileinstall.noInitialDelay", "true");
    System.setProperty("felix.fileinstall.poll", "1000");
    System.setProperty("felix.fileinstall.dir", "./hot-deploy");

    System.out.println("Building OSGi Framework");

    FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();

    // make sure the cache is cleaned
    config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT);

    // more properties available at: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-service-component-runtime.html
    config.put("ds.showtrace", "true");
    config.put("ds.showerrors", "true");

    Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);
    framework.start();

    // declarative services dependency is necessary, otherwise they won't be picked up!
    loadScrBundle(framework);

    BundleContext context = framework.getBundleContext();
    List<Bundle> installedBundles = new LinkedList<>();

    //installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:./Sandbox/osgiTest/module-a/target/module-a-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"));

    for (Bundle bundle : installedBundles) {
        if (bundle.getHeaders().get(Constants.FRAGMENT_HOST) == null) {
            bundle.start();
        }
    }

    try {
        framework.waitForStop(0);
    } finally {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

private static void loadScrBundle(Framework framework) throws URISyntaxException, BundleException {
    URL url = Activator.class.getClassLoader().getResource("org/apache/felix/scr/ScrService.class");
    if (url == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not find the class org.apache.felix.scr.ScrService");
    }
    String jarPath = url.toURI().getSchemeSpecificPart().replaceAll("!.*", "");
    System.out.println("Found declarative services implementation: " + jarPath);
    framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(jarPath).start();
}
```

Comment: I think the main issue is that you don't pass the system props to the felix framework itself which means felix won't be able to get your "felix.fileinstall.dir" property. See https://github.com/apache/felix/blob/e65fb0f35306b553bc3ae0be8eb16190fb818bae/main/src/main/java/org/apache/felix/main/Main.java#L233 for how the felix starter itself handles system props.

Comment: I've looked through the code and I have tried to set `SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_PROP` as a system property pointing to a `config.cfg` file that defines the `felix.fileinstall.dir` property. However, I'm getting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `felix.fileinstall` itself is a bundle that must be started in the host application before it can watch a directory. All that is required from my initial implementation to work is to install and start the `fileinstall` bundle:

```
installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("file:path/to/fileinstall.jar"));
```

Comment: Hi @tarka. I'm trying to learn how to auto-start bundles from a hot-deploy folder, but can barely get any tutorials on felix.fileinstall. Do you know of a good SSCCE reference, or any good tutorial? Thank you. Hope you can help.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev Tutorials a re a little thin on the ground! Basically if you use the code from the OQ. The only addition to the original code is that you will need to download (or compile) the `fileinstall.jar` and actually register that jar as an OSGi dependency at startup. Basically use the code in my reply but change the path to point to your `fileinstall.jar`. That should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of the Felix AutoProcessor and pass the properties to it as well to the framework.

```
final Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
// Probably there is a much better way to o this...
System.getProperties().forEach((key, value) -> config.put(key.toString(), value.toString()));

// Set the properties
config.put(AutoProcessor.AUTO_DEPLOY_DIR_PROPERTY, "hot-deploy");
config.put(AutoProcessor.AUTO_DEPLOY_ACTION_PROPERTY, "install,update,start");
config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT);
config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE, "cache");
```

Then instantiate the framework and run the AutoProcessor as followed:

```
final FrameworkFactory factory = new org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory();
final Framework framework = factory.newFramework(config);

try
{
    framework.init();

    AutoProcessor.process(config, framework.getBundleContext());

    FrameworkEvent event;

    do
    {
        framework.start();
        event = framework.waitForStop(0L);

    } while (event.getType() == 128);

}
catch (final Throwable e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`AutoProcessor.process` calls `AutoProcessor.processAutoDeploy` then, which auto deploys the bundles at startup.
Without calling `AutoProcessor.process` it won't work which probably was your issue.

Comment: This is the closest yet. You are absolutely correct that this now allows me to define the deploy directory and it does in fact deploy the jar bundles located in the directory at startup. However, it does not uninstall the modules at runtime when they are removed from the directory nor does it install them at runtime from the directory. (NB. I added `uninstall` to the actions)

Comment: Your above code seems to be implementing [bundle auto-deploy](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-usage-documentation.html#bundle-auto-deploy) instead of the [file install](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-file-install.html)

Comment: I'm using this code in a launcher https://gist.github.com/Naios/8f5790bce28fae39de9a and it deploys and starts the bundles as exspected. You can handle hot deploy through a 3. party bundle (probably there is something in apache karaf for this).