# Apache felix : Loading bundle files from dir with Felix embedded

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am using Apache Felix in embedded manner as explained in http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html

As per the discussion in [Apache Felix File Install jar from deploy folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386722/apache-felix-file-install-jar-from-deploy-folder)

1) Started felix

2) Installed/started felix.fileinstall bundle on it

3) Set the System proper to hotdiploy dir i.e

> System.setProperty("felix.fileinstall.dir",
>   "file:C:/myrproject/hotdeploy");

I can see bundles in the dir are registered. But is there away that I can get notification when this dir change (adding or deleting new bundles)? 
So in that case I can check for non started bundles and start them. That will help to work hot deployment feature realtime.

Thanks

Comment: Java 7 has API for watching directories, but you will have the problem that your code might be called before the code of fileinstall.

Comment: FileInstall already automatically starts the bundles it finds in the load directory -- assuming you have the `felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start` property set to true (which is the default). So what is the problem you're solving exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `org.apache.felix.eventadmin` bundle, and then watch event topic `org/osgi/framework/BundleEvent/STARTED`. Have a look at [felix eventadmin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-event-admin.html).

Note that the felix web console is a good tool to watch events, at least for debugging purpose.

Comment: There's no need to go to EventAdmin for this. You can register a `BundleListener` directly with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your question includes "a way that I can get notification when this dir change (adding or deleting new bundles", you're probably looking for [the Apache Felix File Install bundle](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-file-install.html); see also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386722/apache-felix-file-install-jar-from-deploy-folder).